# Error in grep command to exit from a Unix Script

Tags: grep, logs, exit

I have a log file created while running a script.

I want to check the same log file for any messages with 'Msg ....' and exit the code except with this 'Msg 2714'.

So, I had added the below code into my script:

```
Some line of code before

rc1=`grep -v 'Msg 2714' $Logfilename`
rc2=`grep -i 'Msg' $rc1`

if [ $rc2 -ne "" ]
then
    echo "Error message, some query has failed"
    exit
fi
```

But, i have been encountering through a problem with the grep command, even though the second grep returns null the exit code/return code is '1' so the- "if commands fails and the exists the script".

Please provide any suggestion if any thing was wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: `$rc1` is not a valid filename.

Comment: Thank you for update. Then could you let me know how can we grep data stored from rc1 variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script uses the value of `$rc1` as a filename, but this is the output of `grep`.

To feed the output of the first `grep` into another `grep`, use a pipe:

```
grep -v ... filename | grep ...
```

Instead of saving the result of `grep` in variables (which can presumably be quite big), let the `if` test act directly on the result of running this pipeline:

```
if grep -v -F 'Msg 2714' "$Logfilename" | grep -q -F Msg; then
    echo 'Error message, some query has failed' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

This uses the exit status of the pipeline (which will be the exit status of `grep -q`) to determine whether the script should output the error message and quit.  No data needs to be stored in variables.

`grep -q` will not output anything but will exit successfully if the given pattern matches. I've also used `-F` with both invocations of `grep` as we are matching strings, not regular expressions.

I'm also following the general guideline that error messages are generated on the standard error stream (with `echo ... >&2` in this case) and that the script will terminate with a non-zero exit status upon a fatal error.

Also possibly relevant, regarding your non-quoting of variable expansions:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used unusual greps to complicate the code. Read your complete explanation and man page about grep -q option. It worked fine for me now.. thank you.